# Notation for the function space of continuous functions defined on a close interval

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, function-spaces

I have a quick question about the proper way of denoting the function space of continuous functions defined on a close interval. for example the function space of Legendre Polynomial.
I think it probably looks like $C({\mathbb{R}(a,b)})$, but couldn't be sure, could you help me with it?

Also a related question, how then to denote the function space defined by $C({\mathbb{S}^3}) \times C({\mathbb{R}(a,b)})$, basically the function space of all continuous functions defined within a 3D sphere of certain diameter?

(I assumed $C({\mathbb{S}^3})$ is the space of continuous functions defined on a spherical surface, basically thespace spanned by spherical harmonics, please let me know if I'm using it wrong).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The notation varies from source to source, just define what it is that you mean. I personally have most recently seen $C^r([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ to denote the space of real-valued $C^r$ functions on $[a,b]$. With this notation, your second space would be $C^0(S^2_r,\mathbb{R})$, assuming that your continuous functions are scalar-valued.

Comment: @William Thank you very much for your help! A quick question, if I understand correctly, $C(S^2_r, R)$ is the space of functions defined on the surface of 3D sphere right? Is there by any chance a compact notation for $C([0,r],\mathbb{R}) \times C(S^2_r, \mathbb{R})$, which is basically continuous functions defined within the 3D sphere of radius $r$?

Comment: Also, would mind clarifying what does the $r$ in the superscript of $C^r([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Comment: A $C^r$ function is an $r$th order continuously differentiable function. So $C^0$ functions are continuous, $C^1$ functions have a continuous derivative, and so forth. $C^\infty$ functions are smooth-- one example is $e^x$.